# TypeError - Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this piece of code, the shell outputs the error 'Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly'.

I have tried other fixes on StackOverflow, however I wasn't able to fix the issue in my code.

```
import math
while True: 
    try:
        di = input('Input 7 digit number ')
        total = (int(di[0])+int(di[2])+int(di[4])+int(di[6]))*3+(int(di[1])+int(di[3])+int(di[5]))
    if len(str(di)) != 7:
        print('Incorrect')           
    if len(str(di)) == 7:
        print('Okay')
        multiplier = [3,1]
        times = ''
        total = 0     
        for index, digit in enumerate(list(str(di))):            
            total = total + int(digit)*multiplier[index%2]               
            times = times+str(int(digit)*multiplier[index%2])+', '          
        mof10 = total + (10 - total%10)          
        checkdigit = mof10 - total
        final = str(di) + str(checkdigit)
        print(times[:-1]) 
        print(total)
        print(mof10)
        print(checkdigit)
        print(final)
    final = (di[1]+di[3]+di[5])+((di[0]+di[2]+di[4]+di[6])*3)
    final = (final+4)
    Base10=(int(round(final, -1)))
    Check = Base10-final
    checkdigit = int(input('8th number in product code: '))
    if (n8 == Check):
        print('Valid product code')
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid product code')
    break
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\GTIN-8 product code.py", line 55, in 
>           final = (final+4)
>
> TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of the error message instead of just your summary of the error

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to do that :P

Comment: Sorry I'm not too familiar with stack overflow yet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first get the value `d1` as a `str`

```
di = input('Input 7 digit number ')
```

Then you get `final` by

```
final = (di[1]+di[3]+di[5])+((di[0]+di[2]+di[4]+di[6])*3)
```

Therefore `final` is a `str` too, so you can't do

```
final = (final+4)
```

because `final` is a `str` and `4` is an `int`

Answer (score 4):

You can't add integers to strings in Python. You need to convert them both to integers or strings.

```
final = int(final) + 4  # convert final from string to integer and add 4
```

or

```
final = final + '4'  # append the string '4' to the end of the string final.
```

Changing the above line will stop the error, but I think you have other parts of your code where you are using strings where you should be using integers.

For example, If `di=1234567`, then `di[0]`, `di[1]`, and so on are strings.

Therefore `di[0]+di[2]+di[4]+d[6]` is the string '1357', not `1+3+5+7=16`. And when you do `di[0]+di[2]+di[4]+d[6]` * 3, the string is repeated three times '135713571357'.

You might find it easiest if you create a list of integers at the beginning of your code:

```
di = [int(x) for x in str(di)]
```

Then `di[0]`, `di[1]` and so on will be integers.